# PHP: $_POST cannot retrieve existing inputs

Tags: php, html

I'm attempting to make a button that, based on the selected form/inputs on the page, will bring you to a page called "typeDefine.php?openness=3?conscientiousness=2?extroversion=1?agreeableness=2?neuroticism=1"(the numbers varying based on the selected inputs).  However, $selectedNum- the variable that would ideally be containing the $_POST for each input- is returning an error immediately once the page is loaded, saying:

> Undefined index

```
<?php
                
    $typeWords = array("openness", "conscientiousness", "extroversion", "agreeableness", "neuroticism");
    $typeLetters = array("o", "c", "e", "a", "n");
    $typePath = "";
    $correspondingLetters = array("I", "II", "III");

    $isFirst = true;
                
    foreach($typeWords as $typeWord)
    {
        $selectedNum = $_POST[$typeWord];//error here!!!
                    
        if(isset($selectedNum))//if got $typeWord in a form
        {
            $separationChar;
                        
            if($isFirst)
            {
                $separationChar = "?";
                
                $isFirst = false;
            }
            else
            {
                $separationChar = "&";
            }

            $typePath = $typePath . $separationChar . $typeWord . "=" . $selectedNum;//e.g. $typePath = "?openness=3?conscientiousness=2?extroversion=1?agreeableness=2?neuroticism=1" for $_GET method after arriving on next page
        }
    }
                
    echo '<a href = "typeDefine.php' . $typePath . '" class = "button" style = "font-size: 400%; padding: 3.85rem 0;">search for type</a>
                
    <div>';
                    
        foreach($typeWords as $typeWord)
        {
            $typeLetter = substr($typeWord, 0, 1);
                        
            echo '<form method = "post" class = "column">';
                        
                for($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++)
                {
                    echo '<input type = "radio" name = "' . $typeWord . '" id = "' . $typeLetter . $i . '"><label for = "' . $typeLetter . $i . '">' . $correspondingLetters[$i - 1] . '</label>';//sets each input name to $typeWord for $_POST above
                }
                            
                echo '<li class = "textHighlight">' . $typeWord . '</li>
                            
            </form>';
        }
                    
    echo '</div>';
            
?>
```

What can I do to fix this error, in turn filling $typePath and making the script correctly bring you to the desired url upon the button's click?

[image: Here is a screenshot of the page for the sake of comprehension]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not related to the problem, but why don't you use `foreach ($typeWords as $typeWord)`?

Comment: URL parameters are in `$_GET`, not `$_POST`.

Comment: And those URL parameters are not correct. You only have one `?` then separate the rest with `&`

Comment: @Barmar I updated it using foreach like you said, thank you. And I know URL parameters use $_GET, but we're not accessing any parameters through a URL on this page, hence $_POST.

Comment: Most likely the problem is not here then. Just `var_export($_POST);` and let us know what it outputs. If nothing then the error is on the previous page.

Comment: @Andreas I updated it to use & instead of ? after the first param.  And I think that's the root of the problem! It outputs "Array()" for $_POST.

Comment: Yes that is what I expected. Your POST of the array is unsuccessful from the previous page. None of the answers here will solve that problem, but they are non the less something you should take note of.

Comment: @Andreas What do you mean by, my $_POST of the array is unsuccessful from the previous page, and what can I do to fix it?  I appreciate the help.

Comment: We can't help you if we don't know how you post the variables from the previous page. Do you use a form or what? We need to see that.

Comment: The variables should be getting retrieved from this page.  The forms are in the code above, but I will post the code again here: echo '<form method = "post" class = "column">'; inputs are used within each form as well.

Comment: Not sure.. I'm not good with forms myself especially not forms on the same page, I have never done that. But perhaps you must have the action part of the form and direct to the same page. `action="page.php"`

Comment: @Andreas Thanks for the suggestion!  Unfortunately, this didn't seem to change anything.  Perhaps this is because the form is not being submitted?

Comment: You don't submit it? I'm quite sure that is the problem then

Answer (score 1):

You should perform the `isset()` test on the `$_POST` element, not the variable that you set from it.

```
    foreach ($typeWords as $typeWord)
    {
        if (isset($_POST[$typeWord])) {
            $selectedNum = $_POST[$typeWord];
            $typePath = $typePath . "?" . $typeWord . "=" . $selectedNum;
        }
    }
```

Note that multiple parameters need to be separated with `&`, `?` should only be used at the beginning. There's a built-in function that will create a query string from an array, you can use that:

```
    $typeArray = [];
    foreach ($typeWords as $typeWord)
    {
        if (isset($_POST[$typeWord])) {
            $selectedNum = $_POST[$typeWord];
            $typeArray[$typeWord] = $selectedNum;
        }
    }
    $typePath = $typePath . "?" . http_build_query($typeArray);
```

You can also replace the loop with:

```
$typeArray = array_intersect_key($_POST, array_flip($typeWords));
```

Comment: Thank you for your response!  I will incorporate that into my code to increase efficiency, and update for $typePath.  However, the error still persists.  Andreas told me to return var_export($_POST); and it returns "Array()", so the roots must be deeper than this code.

Comment: That means you have no post parameters. Does the form use `method="post"`?

Comment: Yup!  Here's the line of code that establishes the form: echo '<form method = "post" class = "column">'; It creates the forms successfully as it visualizes them on the page, so I'm confused as to why it doesn't retrieve any parameters.

Comment: Maybe there's a redirect involved? Check the Network tab of the browser to see how you're calling the script and what parameters are being sent.

Comment: I checked the Network tab of the browser, and in the first 0.25 ms, types.php is called, which is the script we're currently on.  I don't know how to check which parameters are being checked though.

Comment: When you click on a call, the right side will have tabs like `Headers`, `Preview`, `Response`, etc. The Headers tab will show the post parameters at the bottom.

Comment: Thank you!  It says Request Method: GET under general.  I do not see any Post parameters.

Comment: Are you submitting the form normally, or are you using AJAX?

Comment: If the form has `method="post"`, it should say Request Method: POST.

Answer (score 0):

You execute your code immidiately without a present $_POST array.

You have to wrap your post related code with an if statement like this:

```
if ($_POST) {
    $selectedNum = $_POST[$typeWord];
}
```

Comment: Well. That won't solve the problem only eliminate the error.

Comment: Thanks for the answer; it removed the error, but it didn't fix the problem.